# Getting InnerHtml from a javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, getelementbyid

I make an ajax call from my page , and then in response I also get some html like this

```
<parent id="1"><child></child></parent>
```

what I want is to get Inner HTML from the Response object excluding `<parent>`
How can I do that?
Cant use `document.getElementbyID` on a variable.

Comment: do you want `<child></child>`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes exactly..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can create a jQuery wrapper for the variable content and then extract the inner html using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
var data = '<parent id="1"><child></child></parent>'
var x = $(data).html()
```

Comment: where data is the JS variable?

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS if you like -> 
http://jsfiddle.net/eztZm/

```
//get
var get_html = document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML;
console.log(get_html);
//set 
document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML = "new html";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

html code used:

```
<parent id="1"><child>candy</child></parent>
```

first approach:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("1");
var child_text = parent.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

to make a long story short:

```
document.getElementById("1").firstChild.innerHTML
```

will deliver "candy" (without jQuery) :)