# Google Maps API: When infowindow closes, map zooms back to center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple markers on a google map that -- when clicked on -- open up an infowindow. The problem is, when the infowindow is on the periphery of the map, it resets the center of the map. I want to have the map zoom back to the original center after the infowindow closes.

I'm thinking I could do something like the following:

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(infowindow, "close", function() {
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, "close");
   map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(53.0,-1.0));
}); //pseudo-code`

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

use  `setzoom`

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(infowindow, "close", function() {        
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "close");
      map.setZoom(8);
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(53.0,-1.0)); 
}); //pseudo-code
```

**Explaination:**
      we already defined map so use map object to set zoom level or relocation(setCenter)

Comment: Please don't simply post the code. Give some explanation or information or usage about your code. For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384868/getting-innerhtml-from-a-javascript-variable/19384887#19384887).

Comment: we already defined map so use map object to set zoom level or relocation(setCenter)